# Keep special chars when writing to file

Tags: php

i've created a website which contains a form. When submitting the text will be printed into a .csv file.
The problem is that letters like Å Ä Ö is printed as "Ã¥" or "Ã¤". What can I do to keep the letters?

```
<?php
   $fname = $_POST['fname'];
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   $file = "register.csv";  
   $person = $fname.';'. $lname."\n";   
   file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the problem is with reading file. PHP script should store letters the way it receives the letters. 
If you're reading CSV file with Excel - by default encoding would be non-utf. You should check your file with some text editor (or import it to excel setting encoding first), and make sure file is opened as utf-8.

Comment: When opening the file in notepad it showed the right letters. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `UTF-8 BOM`:

```
file_put_contents($myFile, "\xEF\xBB\xBF".  $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```